# JMeter POST/Send files after redirect

Tags: jmeter, spring-webflow

I have a problem with JMeter testing for File Uploads. 
I want to upload a certain XML-file.

When I create the request to `"exampleurl.de/upload"`
the POST date will be only for this URL, but I want to Upload the File to the redirected Page `"exampleurl.de/upload?execution=e3s1"`

But I can't create a Request for the redirected URL.

Is it possible to wait for a redirection and then send the POST request?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the redirect request first and upload request after it. Make sure to put follow redirect checkbox in the HTTP sampler. Jmeter will execute the upload request once the previous redirect request gets the response.

Hope it helps.